# find normalization constant a for $f(x)=a x\sin(x) e^{-x}$

Tags: statistics

The continuous random variable X has the joint probability density

$f(x)=a x \sin(x) e^{-x}$ for

$0<x<\infty$ and 0 otherwise.

Find the normalization constant a.

I am not sure how to find the normalization constant.

Comment: Is $f(4)$ negative?

Answer (score 2):

You know that
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}a\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x=1
$$
Hence you can deduce $a$. If you have difficulties computing the improper integral, I stringly recommend you to see what it looks like in a complex form.
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x=\text{Im}\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{x\left(i-1\right)}\text{d}x\right)=\text{Im}\left(\left[\frac{e^{x\left(i-1\right)}}{i-1}\right]^{+\infty}_{0}\right)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-i}\right)
$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{1-i}=\frac{1+i}{2}
$$
You deduce
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}$$
And finally
$$
a=2
$$

Comment: I think this could a be a comment. The OP is looking for $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x$

Comment: @Alt "I am not sure how to find the normalization constant."

Comment: sorry I for to add an extra x after my a would this change the solution

Comment: You mean $ax \sin(x)e^{-x}$ ??

Comment: yes like that ...

Comment: Yes it changes the value of $a$, but in this case it does not, because as you saw, if I take the real part or imaginary part the result is $1/2$. + integrating by parts, you find $a=2$ anyway

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ is a probability density function:

$\int_{0}^{+\infty}ax\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x=1$

Therefore, $a =\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x}$

And you are lucky because, $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x =\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\sin\left(x\right)e^{-x}\text{d}x = 0.5$

Therefore, $a=2$

Comment: ok that makes sense because the probaility adds up to one